# From two arrays select random one

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays

```js
var array = [{"number": 1}, {"number": 2}]
var array1 = [{"number": 2}, {"number": 3}]
```

I mean from these two variables to randomly select only one, i.e. to have the chance to be selected array but then to have the chance to be selected array1 and so on.

Comment: `var chosen = Math.random()<0.5 ? array : array1`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that takes a variable number of arrays and return one of the at a random index.

```js
const pickOne = (arrays) => {
  return arrays[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrays.length)];
}

var array = [{"number": 1}, {"number": 2}];
var array1 = [{"number": 2}, {"number": 3}];
var array2 = [{"number": 3}, {"number": 4}];

const randomArray = pickOne([array, array1, array2]);
console.log(randomArray);
```